# Installing python module when there are two versions of python installed

Tags: python, pip

I am using ubundu and have python 2X and 3X installed, default version is python 2X. I want to install a package for python3X. When i tried doing it with pip the module got installed to python 2X

Comment: there maybe a pip3 command, use it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip3`:

```
sudo pip3 install 'module'
```

To install `pip3`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

e.g,:

python3.5 -m pip install mypackagename